# has any cycle found in MD5?

Tags: cryptography

We are not sure whether MD5 has fixed point or not. But since the sample space is finite, it must have cycles:

$$ A →(MD5)→ B →(MD5)→ C  →(MD5)→ D  →(MD5)→ A $$

Has any research been done on MD5 to find cycles?

What caused I think about it is that if S is the sample space and R<sub>1</sub> the range of MD5(once or taken in any number) them R<sub>1</sub>⊆S also R<sub>2</sub>⊆R1

MD5(one or multiple): S → R<sub>1</sub>

MD5(one or multiple): R<sub>1</sub> → R<sub>2</sub>

...

Comment: This is not called a *ring*, but a *cycle*.

Comment: @YoniRozenshein thanks I modified. please help in me tagging too if there is any mistake

Comment: There was a distributed computing project to find MD5 cycles, but it was abandoned once a general-purpose collision algorithm was demonstrated in 2004.

Comment: Related info: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26043/how-big-is-the-risk-of-hash-fixed-points-cycles http://elliottkember.com/kember_identity.html

Comment: thank. I was using wrong keyword so I could not find the answer on web. please post solutions as answer to close this thread.

Answer (score 3):

### Not *yet**.

[The only major project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5CRK) to try to find a cycle shut down in 2004 once a [general collision vulnerability was found](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/199), due to the fact that a latter is a *much* more severe vulnerability.

I was [unable to find](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22md5+cycle+found%22) anything other than that Wikipedia article and *this very thread* on the topic. (There is a group that looked into [ways to improve the *internal state*'s cycle length](http://dx.doi.org/10.13052/jcsm2245-1439.623), to help engineer future editions or hash functions to be more robust; however, this is unrelated to cycles of the digest itself when feeding the digest back into the function wholesale.)

### *Do *you* want to find one?

To get a cycle for MD5 would require [nowhere *near* as much power as breaking it](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26063/26186).

Wikipedian [Taxman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Taxman) estimated in 2004 that it would take [a 12.25-Teraflops supercomputing cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_X_(supercomputer)) about 1.77Ms (i.e. just under 3 weeks) to find a cycle. These days, an arbitrary provider, Nimbix, could [allegedly provide this](https://www.nimbix.net/how-much-do-120-teraflops-cost) [if [my math](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=177000+seconds+*+%2812.25%2F120%29+*+%28156+USD%2Fhr%29) is correct] on the order of **1 business day and $800**.

Comment: Given some of the other [zany funds that bored computerists will drop on things](https://twitter.com/fifteenai/status/1360072221000167424), I would hope it's only a matter of time before someone swoops in and finds one.